# Running React native for Windows App

Tags: react-native, msbuild

I installed all required tools for React native Windows Apps but still cannot run the app

React native windows: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows
as you see

react-native run-windows
Scanning 747 folders for symlinks in E:\CrossPlatform\Mero\node_modules (64ms)
Restoring NuGet packages
E:\CrossPlatform\Mero\windows\Mero\Mero.csproj(219,3): error MSB4019: The impor
ted project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\Microso
ft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the
 declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
E:\CrossPlatform\Mero\node_modules\react-native-windows\ReactWindows\ReactNativ
e\ReactNative.csproj(210,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.
targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is co
rrect, and that the file exists on disk.

Failed to restore the NuGet packages
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by uninstalling Visual Studio 2017 and I installed **Visual Studio 2015**